# Validating Name Field With Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am looking for some help on validating the name field with Contact Form 7. I have been getting a lot of spam through and the name field has contained numbers '59ab...'. Looking for a way to validate anything other than numbers. I have tried with jQuery but had no success.

Tried this earlier but unsuccessful.

```
$( ".your-name input" ).change(function() {
var num = $(this).text();
if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
    $(this).attr('class', 'numb');
} else {
    $(this).attr('class', 'noNumb');
}
```

});

Comment: change `$(this).text()` to `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing `$(this).text()` to `$(this).val()` will solve your issue. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$(".myinput").change(function() {
  var num = $(this).val();
  if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
    $(this).attr('class', 'numb');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('class', 'noNumb');
  }
});
```

```css
.numb {
  border-color: green;
}

.noNumb {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myinput">
```

**Update**: Check below snippet. Here I have used regex to detect if there is any number in input.

```js
$(".myinput").change(function() {
  var num = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
  if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
    $(this).attr('class', 'numb');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('class', 'noNumb');
  }
});
```

```css
.numb {
  border-color: green;
}

.noNumb {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myinput">
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the snippet, I see that work for an input value that is only a number, but I need to be able to detect any numbers that are in the string along with letters as the name that causes the spamming includes both. So in theory, if a name is input as '59ab' then toggle the classes?

Comment: do you mean, we need to check if it contains any number in input?